# Did they find evidence of holographic universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, cosmic-microwave-background, holographic-principle

In the [article](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/our-universe-is-a-hologram) they say:

> Theory claims to offer the first 'evidence' our Universe is a hologram

From reading the article I can't really see what the evidence is. Can someone tell me what the claimed evidence is? If so can we now say we live in the holographic universe?

Comment: I think physicsSE would be a much better place to ask about this.

Comment: The actual study that article is referring to is [here](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.041301).

Comment: @DavePhD, it is not a duplicate because I refer the latest study, not the study from 2013. Maybe the question should be if it's the first evidence then if it doesn't fit skeptics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From reading the article I can't really see what the evidence is. Can someone tell me what the claimed evidence is?

The evidence it the microwave frequency data from the [Planck spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)#2015_data_release) as published in [Planck 2015 results](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/abs/2016/10/aa25830-15/aa25830-15.html). The microwaves are from the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background).

> If so can we now say we live in the holographic universe?

No, the [actual article](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.041301) says "We emphasize that the application of holography to cosmology is conjectural, the theoretical validity of such dualities is still open"

Comment: how is the microwave frequency data evidence for it?

Comment: @Grasper hopefully someone will give a better answer than mine, but the Wired article is overstating when that say "contains the first proof".  Instead, the research is comparing the fit of the microwave background to models of the early universe and finds the holographic models fit about as well as the more standard models such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model

Comment: I can't read the PDF, not free, but the abstract also states they have to deal only with multipoles higher than 30, as below it they'd need no perturbative QFT. Low multipoles is larger scale structure. I also can't see if they predict anything different for subsequent observations. Still nice to see not (probably) ruled out.